# iOS App - Native App v Hybrid App

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

iOS App for iPhone, iPad and iPad Mini - Native App v Hybrid App

What are the key differences between a Native App and a Hybrid App from an end-user perspective for iOS Apps for iPhone, iPad and iPad Mini ?

Can end-users detect that an App is a Native App or a Hybrid App ?

Are there performance or functional differences or constraints between Native Apps and Hybrid Apps ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Native apps** are built for a specific platform with the platform SDK, tools and languages, typically provided by the platform vendor (e.g. xCode/Objective-C for iOS, Eclipse/Java for Android, Visual Studio/C# for Windows Phone).

**Mobile Web apps** are server-side apps, built with any server-side technology (PHP, Node.js, ASP.NET) that render HTML that has been styled so that it renders well on a device form factor.

**Hybrid apps,** like native apps, run on the device, and are written with web technologies (HTML5, CSS and JavaScript). Hybrid apps run inside a native container, and leverage the device’s browser engine (but not the browser) to render the HTML and process the JavaScript locally. A web-to-native abstraction layer enables access to device capabilities that are not accessible in Mobile Web applications, such as the accelerometer, camera and local storage.

Get FroM [This site](http://icenium.com/community/blog/icenium-team-blog/2012/06/14/what-is-a-hybrid-mobile-app-) read it.

Comment: The above does not answer the question !

Comment: @user1836288 Try clicking the provided link and reading it. I think you'll find it does answer most of your question with the exception of `Can end-users detect that an App is a Native App or a Hybrid App`. The answer to which is; no, not really.

Comment: I'd say they can often tell, as non-native apps tend to be slower and less responsive.